# I've lost the ability to execute any functions. Is there any way around it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm working on a script with notifications at specified date.

Yesterday, I was writing some lines of code responsible for checking dates within selected column with today's/tomorrow's date. At this point, I've lost my ability to execute functions.

I thought that maybe I've written some invalid functions, but I get no errors. My script tries to execute until a timeout occurs.

So I reverted my code to a simple Hello World within MsgBox (that's barely 3 lines of code). **It won't run as well**, timeout again.

Do I have to make a new Google Sheet and deploy a new script every time something like this happens?

Comment: Have you try to close your browser totally and re-open it ? Sometimes, I've gt the same problem, and it solved the problem.

Comment: It didn't help, making a totally new spreadsheet did. Luckily, I had no issues like that later on.